# How I change ValidationMessages.properties with Hibernate Validator?

Tags: annotations, hibernate-validator, message-bundle

I am trying modify default ValidationMessages.properties to other. But I not get it.

My setup:

In Spring.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>text</value>
            <value>error</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="messageSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

In text.properties and tex_XX.properties.

```
edit.profile.password.size=Password must be between {min} and {max}
```

Annotation example.

```
@Size(min=4, max=8, message="{edit.profile.password.size}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have Hibernate Validator 4.1 or higher on the classpath even if you use a different validation provider.